# PHP array issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array List that I want to output like my example below. How can I achieve it in PHP?

```
Array List:
array(
  [0] => First,
  [1] => Second,
  [2] => Third,
)

Want to output like this:
array(
  [First] => First,
  [Second] => Second,
  [Third] => Third
)
```

Thanks,
steamboy

Comment: +1 we're all not totally nuts :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and pass two copies of your original array:

```
$new_list = array_combine($list, $list);
print_r($new_list);
```

Maps the contents of the first argument as keys and the contents of the second argument as values, in their defined order.

Comment: why did I miss this?! I should get some sleep now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but this should work

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$value] = $value;
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

That should do it

Answer (score 2):

That is redundancy at its finest. It makes little sense to have keys matching their values, and probably highlights the need for a design change, or a potential optimisation somewhere in your application. Turning this:

```
array(
  [0] => First,
  [1] => Second,
  [2] => Third,
)
```

into this:

```
array(
  [First] => First,
  [Second] => Second,
  [Third] => Third
)
```

effectively reduces the amount of information you are storing, since you the developer *know in advance* that keys should match values.

Comment: In all of my years programming I have never had the key match the value in an associative array. Nor can I think of a good use case for such an array.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I now have confirmation that I'm not totally nuts :)

Comment: I'm glad that you're not totally nuts karim.

Nathan, I do have a good use for this, I need it to output select option values on cakephp. Good for you that you didn't encountered this.

Comment: Thanks @steamboy. Can I ask why you are using an array with matching string key/value pairs?

Comment: @karim, I think he answered that.  Presumably, he wants a `option` tag with matching value and text, and Cake expects these to be the key and value.

Comment: @matthew, you explained it very well. Thanks!

Comment: @steamboy - sorry, did not see the edit on your comment. Fair enough, now it actually makes perfect sense - a framework method for building a select element probably takes an array of `value` => `text` pairs. That said, leaving the values blank should cause the browser to send each option's text as it's value. (I think). Didn't mean to criticize, I genuinely thought that something was amiss.